# How to configure single internal ALB for multiple EKS services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes, aws-application-load-balancer

I am running an AWS EKS cluster and in that, there are multiple applications running, my eks is in a private subnet so to access those applications I am using a VPN and creating internal ALBs to access some application dashboard in the browser. I am able to get their dashboard in the browser but now I am trying to make a single alb to access all these applications.

I want to configure a single alb and with that, I want to call my application which is running in my eks cluster.

Suppose, I have an application **uiserver** running in my eks cluster, I want an ALB on which I call alburl/uiserver/somequery, and then it will direct me to alburl/somequery and also call my specific service uiserver.

I am not getting anything to configure this. If anyone has any idea about configuring of this type of ALB then please reply.

Thanks

Comment: Are looking for path based routing.  Following link has details https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-achieve-path-based-routing-alb/